# Domain search availability of my domain.* (any TLD)

Tags: domains

I've spent hours looking for this and I'm surprised I haven't found one:

Where can I do a domain availability search that searches all TLDs including all gTLDs for a given query like `mydomain.*`?

Comment: Is there something specific about your requirements? Because, as @Steve suggests, every domain registrar in existence appears to offer this service?!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this the sort of thing almost every domain registrar offers?  For example [http://www.enom.com/domainsearch/search-results.aspx?sld=stackoverflow&tld=ninja&searchedDomain=stackoverflow](http://www.enom.com/domainsearch/search-results.aspx?sld=stackoverflow&tld=ninja&searchedDomain=stackoverflowhttp://www.enom.com/domainsearch/search-results.aspx?sld=stackoverflow&tld=ninja&searchedDomain=stackoverflow)

Comment: Absolutely! GoDaddy, DomainTools, etc. This has been around since the beginning and at one point you could not swing a dead geek without hitting one!!